# build spring boot project without instantiating mongo

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot

I have a spring boot project with mongo dependency. Building using `mvn clean package` works using `spring.data.mongodb.host=localhost` but when I use `spring.data.mongodb.host=<remote-ip-address>` it fails. As I don't have access to ip address on my local machine, can I build jar without spring trying to connect to mongo.

Right now it's giving below error -

`Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/mongo/MongoDataAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate]: Factory method 'mongoTemplate' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting for a server that matches WritableServerSelector. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=10.37.130.100:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Exception receiving message}, caused by {java.net.SocketException: Operation timed out}}]; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting for a server that matches WritableServerSelector. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=10.37.130.100:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Exception receiving message}, caused by {java.net.SocketException: Operation timed out}}]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In build of Spring Boot application by default there is a test, which checks context, and it's turned on. Just turn off it (-DskipTests property).

Or build with -Dspring.data.mongodb.host=localhost for integration test.

Comment: this worked for me - looks like even specifying a URI you need to put a host as well if its not localhost